# Should I continue to interview during the background check?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, hiring-process, ethics

I signed and accepted an offer recently with company X. I completed my drug test and currently in the process of background check. But the start day of this offer is one month away from now, and I have an interview with company Y coming up next week.

I know I want to work for company X no matter if I receive an offer from company Y or not. I think I can pass the background check since I don't have any criminal records. But people mentioned companies sometime rescind the offer due to budget cut, change in policy, etc. Anything can happen in one month, I don't want to be in a situation if company X rescinds the offer and I lose other opportunities.

1) I am not sure if continue to interview after accepting an offer is the right thing to do, should I continue to interview? What if the company X rescind the offer?

2) When is the exact time I can stop looking for jobs and interview? After a background check? First day of work?

Comment: Continue to interview until you are sure you have a new job.

Answer (score 3):

Until you have returned a signed offer letter that has zero contingencies, you are smart to keep applying and interviewing.

Examples of contingencies are: contract award, background check, drug test, customer approval....

As long as there are contingencies they can easily delay your start date, or cancel the offer. So today you evaluate company X as a better situation, but in a few weeks that might not be true.

Don't think to much about this. Employers know that people who are looking for jobs are juggling multiple situations, each of which is at a different stage of the process.

Answer (score 2):

Check your offer letter/email, it will likely say something like:

> This offer is subject to drug test and background check

At the point you pass both, it becomes **unconditional** and you are safe to stop looking/resign etc (well as safe as you can be, check local labour laws).

Until then continue on any other interviews.

Answer (score 0):

> What if the company X rescind the offer?

Don't worry about the impact on company X, it's the impact on YOU that you should be concerned about - starting with "can you afford it?" If you decide you can't, then keep looking as a matter of due diligence.

> I know I want to work for company X no matter if I receive an offer from company Y or not.

Okay, if Company X rescinds its offer, do you think that working for company Y is preferable to being at your current position? I assume that the answer must be "yes", because it wouldn't make sense for you to interview with Y if you have no reason to believe that being at Y is better than where you currently are, right? Always have a plan B, if possible.

> When is the exact time I can stop looking for jobs and interview? After a background check? First day of work?

I personally am hyper cautious. I usually stop looking by the end of my first month on the job - well after I've got and cashed my first paycheck. I remember once telling my new company that I needed to take time off for that interview because it had been scheduled in advance and I couldn't get out of it. Okay, I admit it - I am a jerk :)

Comment: ***"Okay, I admit it - I am a jerk :)"*** <- Laughing. Out. Loud.